# How can I share my laptop 3G connection with another laptop using Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, 3g

I have an Intel laptop with Wi-Fi running Windows Vista, and connected to the Internet using the [Huawei 3G key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_E220). Can I share this connection using Wi-Fi with another laptop/device?

I can't find an ad hoc Wi-Fi network option, maybe because I'm not using a wired connection.

Any solution?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Ad-hoc-networking-How-the-network-with-the-funny-name-can-make-your-life-easier

and

http://www.home-network-help.com/ad-hoc-wireless.html

Comment: @Idigas , Thanks, but like i said, i DON'T have an Ad Hoc Wi-Fi Network option

Comment: What? at all ? tried looking in your system hardware/properties on wireless card options ? If it doesn't show up even there, then I'm sorry to say, you're probably out of luck (like Molly already indicated).

Comment: All WiFi cards should support Ad-Hoc, which is what you need for Wil's answer. Only some cards support AccessPoint, which is what you need for Molly's answer. They are two different modes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.

Go to `Network  and Sharing Center` and click `Manage network connections`, Right click on the 3g connection and go to properties and on the advanced tab, choose `Share This Connection` and choose the wireless card.

[image]

Next, to set up the ad-hoc connection:

Simply go to `Network and Sharing Center` and click on `Set up a connection or Network`

[image]

Next, choose the Ad-Hoc option.

[image]

Follow the on screen instructions and on the other machine, you should now see the name of the network when you scan from the second machine.

It should all be working now.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, i did all the first steps, but i don't have the "ad hoc" option when i go to setup a connection or network. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: see my answer ... if the card doesn't support it, then this will not work.

Comment: @Unknown Is your wireless card turned on/power on to it? Also, you can try going to "Network and sharing center", then going to "Manage Wireless Networks" and click Add on the toolbar. Ad-Hoc should be an option somewhere along that... @Molly, Ad-hoc is pretty much part of the standard that most laptops for many years supports. It was stated that it can't be found, not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's all guesswork, we don't know the make and model of the laptop or the WLAN adapter. Standard or not, there are quite a few adapters that do not support it.

Comment: @wil please see : http://imgur.com/PFsSB.jpg , and i have 2 network adapters in device manager : Broadcom Netlink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet -- And -- Intel(R) Wifi Link 5100

Comment: Can you go to device manager, expand network connections and take a screenshot there, I think that something else is wrong here...

Comment: Hi, here is it : http://imgur.com/KdCTz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

3G and Wi-Fi (as in "regular" wireless cards) are not the same thing. 3G is, I believe, a trade name for [WiMAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX) standard.
If you mean, sharing the connection via regular wireless cards while being connected to 3G, I guess it would be possible, but IMHO, unusable, since 3G are not exactly broadband connections.

Comment: 3G is what cell-phones use...unrelated to WiMax. 3G is in fact broadband speed, some networks actually support 7.2Mbit/sec connections (UMTS/HSPDA in particular...3G is a somewhat broad term that encompasses several technologies).

Comment: Well, ... I just checked ... dug up one of those little pcmcia cards, and it says 3g and wimax on it...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know they made cards that support both standards. But just because a card supports two different standards, doesn't make them the same thing.

Comment: true ... my mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the WLAN controller is turned ON.

For most laptops you'll have to use a <kbd>FN</kbd> key combination to toggle wireless on/off.

[image]

Some laptops have a physical switch:

[image]

In most cases WLAN ON is indicated by an LED.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i don't understand what do you mean with the adapter ? the key?

Comment: no, the WLAN controller of your laptop, can you open the device manager, expand 'Network adapters' and post the model of your wireless network controller?

Comment: Hi, there are two : Broadcom Netlink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet -- And -- Intel(R) Wifi Link 5100 , and also please see : http://imgur.com/PFsSB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connectify](http://connectify.me/)

Comment: is there something similar to connectify for XP